# Как в потоке вывода std::cout задать количество выводимых символов целых числел либо формат их вывода?

Tags: c++, c++17

У меня есть поток вывода в котором мне надо собрать строку определённого формата. Как мне задать формат потока вывода так что бы выводилось определённое количество символов целого числа. Например если int a = 7 то строка cout << "20" << a; должна вывести `2007` а не `207` или `20 7`. Метод width добивает недостающие позиции пробелами а не '0'. Компилятор gcc 7.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [модификаторы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) [`setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) и [`setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) из заголовочного файла [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip):

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(5) << 12;

выведет:
00012
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/P9w0Lq)

---

Также можно использовать `printf` c форматом `"%0?d"`, где вместо `?` нужно подставить желаемую длину:

```
int dd = 1, mm = 2, yy = 3;
printf("%02d - %02d - %02d", dd, mm, yy);

выведет:
01 - 02 - 03
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/QAuuwX)